# Find out the SP due to which the columns of tables are updated

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the database in which two columns of the tables are updated, but i dont know which SP is executing to update those columns. how can i find out the SP due to which the columns of tables are updated????   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: @marc_s - Your comment is intriguing to me. I would have assumed that the answer would be the same no matter what: That you would have to code a logging mechanism into the stored procedure. By asking to specify an RDBMS, do you mean to imply that there is a built-in mechanism for accomplishing this in at least one common system?

Comment: @gilly3: methods to "observe" or "monitor" database activity are **highly** vendor-specific - one vendor might have a feature / capability that another doesn't have - that's why I'm asking what **concrete database** this is for - the answers for each database might be quite different

Comment: @marc_s  I am using MS-Sql server 2008 R2. can you help find out above problems solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comment clarifying the database you are using, I will suggest installing a tool like RedGate's SQL Search, which is free. Use it to search through your stored procs for the name of the column, and find the code where the update is occurring.

If you cannot deduce which proc is doing the update then you will have to add some logging mechanisms as suggested by gilly3. Perhaps add new columns such as LastUpdateTime and LastUpdateProc, and add code in all procs to update these columns. Additionally, your procs can track their start/stop times by writing to another table meant for tracking proc execution.

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you help me in this module too. I want to create the new trigger which will save the name of the stored procedure which is executed on the particular column of table.

Comment: I have tried this                                                                                            SELECT obj.Name SPName, sc.TEXT SPText
FROM sys.syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON sc.Id = obj.OBJECT_ID
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%' + 'WorkingCSAID' + '%'  
AND TYPE = 'p'   <br>  I am getting the name of SP, But I want the details like which value is updated by each particular SP. In short I want the details like updated column name and SP. can we store the name of SP which is executed on table in trigger.